# Custom joined SQL to ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

DB - PostgreSQL
Rails - 4

I have next SQL

```
sql = <<-SQL
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(id) AS sum_ids, some_key FROM second_models
    WHERE id < 10000
    GROUP BY some_key
  ) AS second_models ON first_models.id = second_models.first_model_id
SQL
record = FModel.joins(sql).last

record.sum_ids # DOESN'T WORK !
```

and I can see the record as ActiveRecord object, but **can I get somehow field** `sum_ids` which was built manually?

Comment: Try creating an `attr_acessor` to the model

Comment: To access it you'd need a method that returns it on your model.

Comment: @vnbrs doesn't work

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321340/is-it-possible-to-define-virtual-attributes-in-activerecord-corresponding-to-sql

Comment: @LucasWieloch I can't realy understand how can I implement it? Can you add short example?

Comment: @OlegSobchuk I cannot remember a *rails way* of doing it right now, and I'm not with RoR on this machine. I haven't tried BenToogood 's suggestion but it seems that is close to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The additional field is inside the join section. It is not selected by default and thus can't be read. When executing your statement you get something like the following SQL query:

```
SELECT first_models.*
FROM first_models
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(id) AS sum_ids, some_key
    FROM second_models
    WHERE id < 10000
    GROUP BY some_key
  ) AS second_models
  ON first_models.id = second_models.first_model_id
```

The first select statement prevents the `sum_ids` field from being accessible in your object since it's never returned to Rails. You want to change `SELECT first_models.*` to `SELECT *`. This is simply done by specifying the following select:

```
record = FModel.select(Arel.star).joins(sql).last
record.sum_ids
#=> should now give you your value
```

You can also add your field specifically using the following method:

```
f_models = FModel.arel_table
record = FModel.select(f_models[Arel.star]).select('sum_ids').joins(sql).last
```

This should result in `SELECT first_models.*, sum_ids`.

Comment: If you prefer to select the fields after the join you can do so without issue. I personally like to keep the SQL structure. (select -> joins (from) -> where -> group -> having -> order)